# How to finish activity after authentication success

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to finish the login activity after the fingerAuthentification success, I have tried using "finish()" and "finishAffinity()" but I get an error "cannot resolver method finish() or finishAffinity()

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
    private Context context;

    public FingerprintHandler(Context mcontext) { context = mcontext; }

    public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
        cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Authentication error\n" + errString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication help\n" + helpString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Authentication Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Handler hd = new Handler();
        hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                FingerLogin.finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole class.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I have updated my question with the whole java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it before, but theoretically this should work:

Step 1: In the constructor pass an `Activity` instead of `Context`. This is the 
         activity you want to finish.

Step 2: Assign this activity to a private variable.

Step 3: Call `finish()` on the variable when needed.

The code would be something like:

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
    private Activity activity;

    public FingerprintHandler(Activity mActivity) { activity = mActivity; }

    .....

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Authentication Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Handler hd = new Handler();
    hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
            activity.finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Works great! exactly what I needed. Thank you bro

Answer (score 2):

`finish()` is a method on `Activity`, not `Context`. You can't finish a context. It's unclear if you are running in the context of an activity or not. If you are, just call `finish()` on yourself (or `YourActivity.this.finish()`).

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I tried FingerLogin.this.finish() and get the error " Non-static method 'finish()' cannot be referenced from a static contenxt

Comment: No you didn't do that. You tried `FingerLogin.finish()`, not `FingerLogin.this.finish()`. The former is attempting to call the static method `finish()` on the `FingerLogin` class, which doesn't exist.

Comment: My bad, if I use FingerLogin.this.finish() new errer "is not an enclosing class"

Comment: You either need to have a handle to the activity you want to finish, or you need to make that activity accept an intent action that instructs it to finish (or otherwise come up with a method to pass it a message telling it to finish).

Answer (score 1):

**Use this to access your activity's override methods:**

```java
           if(context instanceof FingerLogin){
                   ((FingerLogin)context).finish();
           }
```